# "Unsupported state or unable to authenticate data" with aes-128-gcm in Node

Tags: node.js, encryption, aes-gcm

I'm trying to implement encrypt/decrypt functions using aes-128-gcm as provided by node crypto. From my understanding, gcm encrypts the ciphertext but also hashes it and provides this as an 'authentication tag'. However, I keep getting the error: "Unsupported state or unable to authenticate data".

I'm not sure if this is an error in my code - looking at the encrypted ciphertext and auth tag, the one being fetched by the decrypt function is the same as the one produced by the encrypt function.

```
    function encrypt(plaintext) {
    // IV is being generated for each encryption
    var iv = crypto.randomBytes(12),
        cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(aes,key,iv),
        encryptedData = cipher.update(plaintext),
        tag;

    // Cipher.final has been called, so no more encryption/updates can take place
    encryptedData += cipher.final();

    // Auth tag must be generated after cipher.final()
    tag = cipher.getAuthTag();

    return encryptedData + "$$" + tag.toString('hex') + "$$" + iv.toString('hex');
}

function decrypt(ciphertext) {
    var cipherSplit = ciphertext.split("$$"),
        text = cipherSplit[0],
        tag = Buffer.from(cipherSplit[1], 'hex'),
        iv = Buffer.from(cipherSplit[2], 'hex'),
        decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(aes,key,iv);

    decipher.setAuthTag(tag);

    var decryptedData = decipher.update(text);

    decryptedData += decipher.final();
}
```

The error is being thrown by decipher.final().

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I managed to fix this: the issue was that I wasn't specifying an encoding type for cipher.final() and I was returning it within a String, so it wasn't returning a Buffer object, which decipher.final() was expecting.

To fix, I add 'utf-8' to 'hex' encoding parameters within my cipher.update and cipher.final, and vice versa in decipher.

**Edited to add code example - note this is from 2018, so may be outdated now.**

```
function encrypt(plaintext) {
    // IV is being generated for each encryption
    var iv = crypto.randomBytes(12),
        cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(aes,key,iv),
         encryptedData = cipher.update(plaintext, 'utf-8', 'hex'),
        tag;

    // Cipher.final has been called, so no more encryption/updates can take place
     encryptedData += cipher.final('hex');

    // Auth tag must be generated after cipher.final()
    tag = cipher.getAuthTag();

    return encryptedData + "$$" + tag.toString('hex') + "$$" + iv.toString('hex');
}

function decrypt(ciphertext) {
    var cipherSplit = ciphertext.split("$$"),
        text = cipherSplit[0],
         tag = Buffer.from(cipherSplit[1], 'hex'),
            iv = Buffer.from(cipherSplit[2], 'hex'),
            decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(aes, key, iv);


    decipher.setAuthTag(tag);

    var decryptedData = decipher.update(text, 'hex', 'utf-8');

   decryptedData += decipher.final('utf-8');
}
```

Comment: Could you please share a code example of doing this :)

Comment: If you're using GCM or similar make sure to set the authTag https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53269132/aes-256-gcm-encryption-decryption-in-nodejs

Comment: Could you please share an example?

Comment: @HenockBongi I've added a code example now. Note this project is from 2018, so the code may now be outdated if the library has been updated.

Answer (score 17):

In case if someone still tries to get a working example of encryption and decryption process.

I've left some comments that should be taken into consideration.

```js
import * as crypto from 'crypto';

const textToEncode = 'some secret text'; // utf-16
const algo = 'aes-128-gcm';

// Key bytes length depends on algorithm being used:
// 'aes-128-gcm' = 16 bytes
// 'aes-192-gcm' = 24 bytes
// 'aes-256-gcm' = 32 bytes
const key = crypto.randomBytes(16);

const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);
const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algo, key, iv);

const encrypted = Buffer.concat([
  cipher.update(Buffer.from(textToEncode, 'utf-8')),
  cipher.final(),
]);

const authTag = cipher.getAuthTag();

console.info('Value encrypted', {
  valueToEncrypt: textToEncode,
  encryptedValue: encrypted.toString('hex'),
  authTag: authTag.toString('hex'),
});

// It's important to use the same authTag and IV that were used during encoding
const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algo, key, iv);
decipher.setAuthTag(authTag);

const decrypted = Buffer.concat([
  decipher.update(encrypted),
  decipher.final(),
]);

console.info('Value decrypted', {
  valueToDecrypt: encrypted.toString('hex'),
  decryptedValue: decrypted.toString('utf-8'),
});
```

Comment: I think JS defaults to UTF16 for strings, so your line of code `const textToEncode = 'some secret text'; // utf-8` should say `//utf16` right?

Comment: this saved my skin - I wasn't using the auth tag and couldn't figure it out from the documentation. You are my saviour!!!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite old, but came across when trying to connect a NodeJS backend with iOS Swift developed app. The answers did not worked, but give me the hint to create this GIST.
[See a detailed implementation](https://gist.github.com/BigEdu/5696ea4fc704df7df516ccc1e06306b1)

iOS Swift uses CryptoKit with AES.GCM and packs (data, IV and authTag).
[Apple's SealedBox documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cryptokit/aes/gcm/sealedbox)

Then you need to play around to pack/unpack IV, cipher and authTag in a way you can send to Apple's CryptoKit in a "sealed box".

```
    const buffer = require('buffer');
    const myCrypto = require('crypto');
    
    const aes256gcm = (key) => {
      const ALGO = 'aes-256-gcm';
    
      const encryptToSealedBox = (clearText) => {
        // do the usual encription process
        const iv = Buffer.from(myCrypto.randomBytes(12), 'utf8');
        const cipher = myCrypto.createCipheriv(ALGO, key, iv);
    
        let enc = cipher.update(clearText, 'utf8', 'base64');
        enc += cipher.final('base64');
        let tag = cipher.getAuthTag();
        // create the SealedBox data structure
        let uiArray = [Buffer.from(enc, 'base64'), tag];
        let finalCipher = iv.toString('base64') + Buffer.concat(uiArray).toString('base64');
        return finalCipher;
    
      };
    
      const decryptFromSealedBox = (b64EncodedCipher) => {
    
        // data received as base64, so, unpack it and make Buffers of IV & AuthTag as required
        // might this code be optimized?... sure, let me know if so... I did it this way to test & worked.. and I understand what's going on
    
        // get IV
        const iv = b64EncodedCipher.substring(0,16);
        const ivBuff = Buffer.from(iv, 'base64');
    
        // get encripted text + authTag
        const cipherBlob = b64EncodedCipher.substring(16);
        const cipherBuff = Buffer.from(cipherBlob, 'base64');
        const cipherTextBuff = cipherBuff.subarray(0, cipherBuff.length-16);
        const tagBuff = cipherBuff.subarray(cipherBuff.length-16);
        const cipherText = cipherTextBuff.toString('base64');
    
        const decipher = myCrypto.createDecipheriv(ALGO, key, ivBuff);
        decipher.setAuthTag(tagBuff);
        let str = decipher.update(cipherText, 'base64', 'utf8');
        str += decipher.final('utf8');
        return str;
      };
    
      return {
        encryptToSealedBox,
        decryptFromSealedBox
      };
    };
    
    //test it
    const KEY = Buffer.from(myCrypto.randomBytes(32), 'utf8');
    const aesCipher = aes256gcm(KEY);
    
    const textToTest = 'I wanna try GCM encryption';
    const textEncrypted = aesCipher.encryptToSealedBox(textToTest);
    const clearFinalText = aesCipher.decryptFromSealedBox(textEncrypted);
    console.log(clearFinalText);
```