# AES 256 GCM encryption decryption in nodejs

Tags: encryption, aes, node.js

I am implementing a basic encryption/decryption set of functions in nodejs and I keep getting the following error in the decryption part:
`Error: Unsupported state or unable to authenticate data`

This is my code so far:

```
import crypto from 'crypto'
import logger from './logger'

const ALGORITHM = 'aes-256-gcm'

export const encrypt = (keyBuffer, dataBuffer, aadBuffer) => {
  // iv stands for "initialization vector"
  const iv = Buffer.from(crypto.randomBytes(12), 'utf8')
  logger.debug('iv: ', iv)
  const encryptor = crypto.createCipheriv(ALGORITHM, keyBuffer, iv)
  logger.debug('encryptor: ', encryptor)
  logger.debug('dataBuffer: ', dataBuffer)
  return Buffer.concat([iv, encryptor.update(dataBuffer, 'utf8'), encryptor.final()])
}

export const decrypt = (keyBuffer, dataBuffer, aadBuffer) => {
  const iv = dataBuffer.slice(0, 96)

  const decryptor = crypto.createDecipheriv(ALGORITHM, keyBuffer, iv)
  return Buffer.concat([decryptor.update(dataBuffer.slice(96), 'utf8'), decryptor.final()])
}
```

My error happens in the last line of the decrypt function.  I am storing the iv as part of the dataBuffer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I might be wrong on this, but isn't the slice specifying the number of bytes (not bits)?  If that is the case, then you should be slicing 12 bytes, not 96.

Answer (score 9):

I realized I had made a couple of mistakes with the original code that I posted, one of them as @TheGreatContini remarked was the size of the slicing which was being done in bits instead of bytes as it should be.  Still, the biggest piece that I was missing was the authTag which always should be included in the decipher function setup.

Here is my working code for anybody interested for future references:

```
import crypto from 'crypto'
import logger from './logger'

const ALGORITHM = 'aes-256-gcm'

export const encrypt = (keyBuffer, dataBuffer, aadBuffer) => {
  // iv stands for "initialization vector"
  const iv = crypto.randomBytes(12)
  const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(ALGORITHM, keyBuffer, iv)
  const encryptedBuffer = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(dataBuffer), cipher.final()])
  const authTag = cipher.getAuthTag()
  let bufferLength = Buffer.alloc(1)
  bufferLength.writeUInt8(iv.length, 0)
  return Buffer.concat([bufferLength, iv, authTag, encryptedBuffer])
}

export const decrypt = (keyBuffer, dataBuffer, aadBuffer) => {
  const ivSize = dataBuffer.readUInt8(0)
  const iv = dataBuffer.slice(1, ivSize + 1)
  // The authTag is by default 16 bytes in AES-GCM
  const authTag = dataBuffer.slice(ivSize + 1, ivSize + 17)
  const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(ALGORITHM, keyBuffer, iv)
  decipher.setAuthTag(authTag)
  return Buffer.concat([decipher.update(dataBuffer.slice(ivSize + 17)), decipher.final()])
}
```