# Using the Node crypto library for some simple private key encryption but getting errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, encryption, cryptography

I'm putting together a quick POC to encrypt an incoming string using a common key. This is what I have in my middleware:

```
import Crypto from 'crypto';

export default async function encrypt(req, res) {
  try {
    let aesKey = "thisisouraestestkey";

    let toEncrypt = req.body.encryptString;
    let buf = Buffer.from(toEncrypt, 'utf8');
    let encryptedString = Crypto.privateEncrypt(aesKey, buf);

    res.status(200).json({ encryptedString });
  }
  catch(err) {
    logger.error(`there was an error: ${err.message}`);
    res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
  }
}
```

I am getting the following error when trying to encrypt:

```
there was an error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
```

After doing a bit of seraching on this error I see a lot of mentions of my local certificate files. I'm not sure why it would be using any local certificates or anything like that. I want this encryption to run the same no matter what machine it is running on so I wouldn't want it to depend on local files.

I'm currently running the project locally but it will be built and deployed to a remote machine.

Comment: You are using "Crypto.privateEncrypt" as encryption function but that uses a private/public key encryption ("asymmetric encryption"). I'm for sure you wanted to use a "symmetric" encryption with AES as cipher and "GCM" as mode. A good starting üpoint could be https://lollyrock.com/posts/nodejs-encryption/..

Answer (score 2):

`crypto#privateEncrypt` expects an RSA private key in order to "encrypt" with a private key. Note that such a thing is usually called "signing" when proper hashing is performed. So `crypto#privateEncrypt` is a low-level primitive to implement your own RSA signing operation. `crypto#publicDecrypt` would be the low-level primitive to implement RSA verification. That's probably too low-level for you. Don't roll your own crypto!

Since your key is short and contains "aes" in a variable name, I suspect you're looking for symmetric encryption or secret-key encryption using AES. [`crypto.createCipheriv`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createcipheriv_algorithm_key_iv_options)  and the Cipher object are your friends for this use case. Note that you have to think about the mode of operation and possibly the padding scheme. I suggest AES-256-GCM as seen in [this implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53272712/1816580).